# How to align Bootstrap dropdown with triggering button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

If I want to have text preceeding my dropdown button on the same line, how can I get the dropdown to align properly?  Using this html, it aligns to the left edge of the div (i.e. the word "Choose").  But if I put the span outside of the dropdown div, the div begins a new line.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span>Choose: </span>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="choice-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Choice 
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="choice-dropdown" id="choice-dropdown-list">
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the dropdown div, and move the span to the outside:

```
<span>Choose: </span><div class="dropdown" style="display:inline-block;">
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks :)  I had forgotten that there was a way to make a div not always start on a new line.

Comment: You can accept this as an answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: It's not allowing me to accept so quickly after it was posted -- I will accept when it lets me :)